# Need to remove all the character after ":" and "-"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two string with the following structure.

```
1 ABCD: PQRS XYZ
2 qwerty-asd zxc
```

I need to remove all the character after ":" and "-"
I have tried the following code.
I want one combined solution for this please help me with this.

```
m = re.sub(r'^-(.*?)', "" ,tags)
print(m)
n = re.sub(r'^:(.*?)', "" ,m)
print(n)
```

Comment: please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Comment: Yes sure, My issue us resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother replacing everything after `:` or `-`, just take whatever is before.

```
import re

li = ['1 ABCD: PQRS XYZ', '2 qwerty-asd zxc']

regex = re.compile(r'(.*)[:|-]')

for string in li:
    print(regex.search(string).group(1))
```

Outputs

```
1 ABCD
2 qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```py
import re

r = re.compile('[-:].+$')

for text in [
  "1 ABCD: PQRS XYZ",
  "2 qwerty-asd zxc",
]:
  print(r.sub('', text))
```

outputs

```
1 ABCD
2 qwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'OR' symbol for regex is `|`:

```
n = re.sub(r'^:|-(.*?)', "" ,m)
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need,

```
tags = 'Name: Raunaq'
m = re.sub(r'[-:](.*)', '', tags)
print (m)
```

**Output** - `'Name:'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slicing` an `index` function, without using another module. like:

```
value1 = "ABCD: PQRS XYZ"
value2 = "qwerty-asd zxc"

result1 = value1[:value1.index(":")]
result2 = value2[:value2.index("-")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.index(':')` and `str.index('-')` to get the indices of the first occurrences of `:` and `-`, respectively.  Then you can use slicing to strip them and everything else off the end.

```
def trimEnd(s):
    if ':' in s:
        s = s[:s.index(':')]
    if '-' in s:
        s = s[:s.index('-')]
    return s

a = 'ABCD: PQRS XYZ'
b = 'qwerty-asd zxc'
print(trimEnd(a))
print(trimEnd(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple solution without using of `re` module:

```
def remove_after(string: str, token: str) -> str:
    return string[:string.index(token)]

proper_string = remove_after('1 ABCD: PQRS XYZ', ':')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a method that would take a string and the char that needs the separation.

```
def strip_off(s, charr):
    if charr in s:
        return s[:s.index(charr)]
    else:
        return charr, " not present in ", s

s1 = '1 ABCD: PQRS XYZ'
s2 = '2 qwerty-asd zxc'

print(strip_off(s1, ":"))
print(strip_off(s2, "-"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 ABCD
2 qwerty
```